# What conditions lead to stalls during Fetch, IQ and decode?

Tags: cpu-architecture

In an in-order fetch, out-of-order decode/execute and in order commit processor with 3 functional units(x: branching, y: ALU + load/store, z: multiplication), and issue queue and a reorder buffer, what kinds of operations would stall the fetch? Stall instruction issue? Stall decode?

Note data hazards and structural hazards are assumed to stall in decode, so what other instruction sequences would stall decode? There are no branches allowed in this example.

In another instance, functional blocks could be multifunctional, like x:branching+alu, y: load/store + alu, z: mult + alu(with stages z0,z1,z2,z3). How would that change the potential for different hazards. So mults take 7 clocks to WB. x and y continue to process while the mults occur, so,their output presumably get stored in the architectural register file.